# Custom Authentication in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking a solution to combine Power BI authentication and a web application.
We authenticate our users using existing web application and let them see the dashboard and reports in Power BI portal, the existing users are external customers who don't have internal AD accounts.

Following solution will redirect user to a login page always.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample

But what I need is that once the user has been authenticated using our web application, Power BI let the users see the dashboards without any more authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed reports in your application, implementing "[app own data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers)" scenario. Basically, your app uses a single Power BI account (master account) to access the reports, while your users are authenticated in your application in another way. Microsoft provides good [examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples) how to do this.

Essentially, you need to use [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) to authenticate your master account and get an access token. Having this access token, you can use [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) to enumerate the reports, dashboards or tiles in some workspace (or to enumerate all workspaces), obtain the [embedUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreport#definitions) of some report (or dashboard, or tile), [generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken/reports_generatetoken) an access token for it and embed it in your application. In this case your users doesn't need Power BI accounts at all.

Comment: Thank Andrey, but our servers and applications are on-premise, we can't use Azure or any other cloud, can I implement your solution without using Azure?

Comment: I do not understand. If you can't use Azure or any cloud, then what are these dashboard and reports in Power BI portal? If you need on premise solution, you can use SSRS or Power BI Reporting Services. In this case embedding reports is easier - just add rs:embed=true parameter to report's URL to embed it into an iFrame. Regarding authentication, I think the best option is your web app to use Windows Authentication to authenticate itself.

Comment: Just a word of warning that using single master account to authenticate with PowerBI Report Server is not secure and will (technically) allow users accessing reports not assigned to them.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you are using PowerBI Report Server and want to change it to not use AD authentication which it does by default.

The repo you linked does this by prompting credentials and verifying them internally.

If you want Report Server to inherit your app authentication you need to modify CustomSecuritySample to not prompt the user login and pass credentials yourself.

For example you could modify `Logon.aspx.cs` `Page_Load()` method to read credentials from a shared cookie, verify them with your internal authentication mechanism and call `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(...)`.

`AuthenticationUtilities.cs` implements credential checking.

You will need to implement some secure way of authenticating users, for example using expiring tokens. You will likely need to extend your internal authentication for this.

In addition to this, you will need to manage report/folder permissions. Depending on how many users you have and unless all users have access to the same reports, you may want to look into [REST APIs for Power BI Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/rest-api)

Answer (score 1):

I forked Microsoft's Custom Security Sample to do just what you are describing (needed the functionality at a client long ago and reimplemented as a shareable project on GitHub).

https://github.com/sonrai-LLC/ExtRSAuth

I created a YouTube walkthrough as well to show how one can extend and debug SSRS security with this ExtRSAuth SSRS security assembly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnsWChwW7lA

TL; DR; just bypass the Microsoft example auth check in Login.aspx.cs and put your auth in Page_Load() or Page_Init() event of Login.aspx.cs- wherever you want to perform some custom logging check- and then immediately redirect auth'd user to their requested URI.

Comment: And here is an example of ExtRSAuth working in an ASP.NET Core (.NET 6) client app: https://c00rds.azurewebsites.net; hope it helps you or others looking to unlock SSRS auth. The example is SSRS but works for PBI && SSRS on same server, all the same.