# Power BI Report Server: Custom Authentication with users of my system

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

Scenario: 
I am trying to do custom authentication( https://github.com/microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample ) in the iframe that will show my report stored on Report Server. I don't want use windows user to authentication, I want use the users of my system.

My doubt:
Is it necessary to register the users of my system in PowerBI Report Server > Report123 > Manage > Security? Or because of custom authentication isn't necessary to register?

Thank You

Comment: Did you try powerbi embedded api?

Comment: WS Ayan, The api works on-prem? ( ReportServer ). I think the api only work on azure.

Comment: I didn’t work with on-premises. Yes it works  on azure.

Comment: My environment is on-premises, we are using PBIRS

Comment: What do you mean by "register"? If you mean assign report permissions, then you can assign these on the folder/report server level to avoid having to set these on each report. You can also look into anonymous authentication in the custom authentication sample if you have to avoid assigning permissions explicitly (if this is compatible with your requirements)

Comment: you can modify CostumeAuthentication like this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61456301/7040747