# Power BI Report Server Custom Authentication: IIS that host the webpage and PBIRS in different machines

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to do custom authentication in my solution that will use Power BI Report Server. The user will see the report through an IFrame pointing to the Report hosted in PBIRS. We want to use CustomAuthentication, only user logged in the site will see the report.

Is It possible to the IIS that will host my Asp page and the PBIRS are in different machines? Or they need to be in the same machine?

I think is not possible, because in one tutorial they said that the IIS web.config and the PBIRS web.config need to have the same machine keys; but I need confirmation.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: It is possible, taken that both machine hard code the same machine key in the web config, and the cookie can be shared.

You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61456301/7040747, this is a solution on how you connect them together.

C# authenticate a user by decrypting the login cookie using the Machine Key. So if your Power BI Report Server (PBIRS) is able to receive the login credential cookie from your ASP, and able to validate the cookie by successfully decrypting it, PBIRS will then be able to authenticate the user who entered the system.