# PowerBI on-premises: Authentication Token without AAD access?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I have an environment that is entirely on-premises( PowerBI Report Server ). I will show my reports to the external users logged in my company site through Iframe.

Problem: External users will see the report on the company page. I need to secure that only users authenticated in my company site( Users logged in my site, not Windows/Network Users ) will be able to open the report link. I don't have access to Azure Active Directory, and my reports are stored on Power BI Report Server( on-premises )

Searching on google I see a solution that uses authentication token and Rest API, but in the tutorial was necessary access to Azure Active Directory. ( [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-your-organization )

Question: Is it possible to use a similar authentication token approach in my company site without the connection to Azure Active Directory? If not possible, there is something that I can do using the Rest API to ensure that only users authenticated in my company site will be able to open the report?

PS: There is an approach, a Custom Authentication code in Github, that create a .dll and this .dll customize the authentication of the ReportServer, but we don't like this solution. We want something more simple, modern, secure and intuitive.

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: As I know there are no any other ways to secure embedded PBI reports (with row-level security), AD is only option. For tabular reports you may consider usage of another on-premise BI products with JWT-based auth.

Comment: What you are asking is possible, check this question which could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164720/custom-authentication-in-powerbi/61456301